# Django - get queryset with id's not in set of values

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

According to doc - 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut - 
I can get set of objects with specified in list ids. Is there any short way to get another set of objects, with id's not in the specified list. Blog.objects.filter(pk__not_in=[1,4,7]) - did not work for me. *PS: is there any annotation of possible expresissions for filtering querysets, of making own short expressions?*

Answer (score 8):

Use the [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) method.

```
Blog.objects.exclude(pk__in=[1,4,7])
```

Answer (score 0):

At first your query is wrong. You should write your query Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,4,7]). And if you want to use not then you should read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)